# While falling into a black hole, what color would the flashlight have?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-redshift

If, hypothetically, me and my rocket powered flashlight were falling straight toward the center of a black hole. The flashlight is a few kilometers behind me in our travels toward the center of the black hole, but since it is rocket powered, it manages to maintain the exact distance to me for a while.

The point is; The distance between me and my flashlight is constant as long as I am observing it.

The photons coming from the flashlight would obviously not be rocket powered - and they would be affected by the black holes gravitation.

Would the light I see from the flashlight be shifted towards red or blue, even though the distance between me and my dear flashlight is maintained?

If so; switching the positions of me and my flashlight, would it change the color I'd observe?

If we turn off the rocket on the flashlight, I assume it would be redshifted regardless of which were closer to the singularity, and the magnitude of redshift would appear to accelerate?

Comment: I've posted this question on astronomy. Should I delete it here?